# Calculating two integers

Tags: java, android, integer, calculator

I'm new to android development, and i've came across my first misunderstanding.

So what i want to do, is make a simple calculator that would return sum of two integers.

My code is:

Main Activity

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edit_message2);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE2, message2);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

DisplayMessageActivity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
String message2 = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2);
int result = Integer.parseInt(message) + Integer.parseInt(message2);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
TextView t = new TextView(this);
t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);
t.setText(String.valueOf(result));
```

Testing gives me these results:

2 + 2 = 4

2 + 3 = 6

1 + 8 = 16

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: show the point of code where you put the extra into the intent

Comment: Looks like the parameters have the same value, show us the code where you create the intent.

Comment: Check if `MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE` and `MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE2` having same value. This is only the reason of this bug.

Comment: @GrIsHu internally `Integer.valueOf()` uses `Integer.parseInt()`. there is no difference...

Comment: We are saying that check value of Keys. Need not more code.

Comment: @PankajKumar is probably right, looks like that the extra keys are the same.

Comment: show the initialization of EXTRA_MESSAGE and EXTRA_MESSAGE2 fields...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for tips! Found the problem initializing EXTRA_MESSAGE variables

It was:

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.m2test.MESSAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE2 = "com.example.m2test.MESSAGE";
```

Instead of:

```
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.m2test.MESSAGE";
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE2 = "com.example.m2test.MESSAGE2";
```